# How i can add where's conditionally when i receive query params in adonis.js/node?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

Actually i have this query that returns all the users in database:

```
async index({request}) {
    const page = request.input('page')
    const pageSize = request.input('pageSize')
    const users = await User
        .query()
        .with('user')
        .paginate(page, pageSize)
    return users.toJSON()
}
```

I need to create conditionally one way to put where in this query if i receive params.

For example, if i receive request.input('username') append one where:

```
.whereRaw('username = %?%', [request.input('username')])
```

I don't find in the documentation something that explain how i can create conditionally where's. Someone can explain me?

**Tried:**

```
async index({request}) {
    const page = request.input('page')
    const pageSize = request.input('pageSize')
    const queryUsers = await User
        .query()
        .with('user')
        .paginate(page, pageSize)

    if(request.input('username'))
        queryUsers.where('username = %?%', [request.input('username')])

    return queryUsers.toJSON()
}
```

But i receive:

> queryUsers.where is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually if you look at this part of the documentation [Query Builder](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/lucid#_query_builder) you'll see that your query is not run until you run `.fetch()` or in your case `.paginate()`. Your code would be something like this:

```
async index({request}) {
    const { page, pageSize } = request.get();
    const queryUsers = User
        .query()
        .with('user')

    if(request.input('username'))
        queryUsers.where('username', '=', request.input('username'))

    const users = await queryUsers.paginate(page, pageSize)

    return users
}
```

Comment: In this case, where i have to put the fetch()?

Comment: This way i'm receiving: "Make sure to call fetch to execute the query". I put the fetch in:         const users = query.paginate(page, pageSize)
        users.fetch()

Answer (score 2):

I fixed with the @VladNeacsu help, my finally code look this way:

```
async index({request}) {
    const { page, pageSize } = request.get();
    const queryUsers = User
        .query()
        .with('user')

    if(request.input('username'))
        queryUsers.where('username', '=', request.input('username'))

    const users = await queryUsers.paginate(page, pageSize)

    return users
}
```

Comment: I was just about to post this working example :) looks good. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `if` helper to write a cleaner version, [documented here](https://docs.adonisjs.com/reference/database/query-builder#if).

```js
async index({request}) {
    const { page, pageSize } = request.get();
    const username = request.input('username')

    const users = await User
        .query()
        .with('user')
        .if(!!username, (query) => {
           query.where('username', '=', username)
        })
        .paginate(page, pageSize)

    return users
}
```